# Is there a way to end the Nutch spider without losing the information you spidered?

Tags: nutch

If I'm in the middle of a spider session and I close the spider all the data won't show up in the index. I would have to wait until the indexing has completed it's self. Is there a way I can end the spider and still be able to search through that data with the Nutch search? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Spider crawls and searching are independent so once you have produced an index you can make it available for search and start crawling your next segment.
So what is it really you are trying to achieve ?